# Neo4j: How to choose database location on LAN network?

Tags: neo4j

I have 2 computers (PC1 and PC2). They are connected via LAN network.
PC1 has IP address: 192.168.1.10
PC2 has IP address: 192.168.1.11
And on PC2, I have a sharing folder. It contain a Neo4j graph database.
Path of this folder: \192.168.1.11\Share\Neo4j\graph.db
How to connect to this database?

Comment: i think neo4j exposes http interface, you can connect via that

Answer (score 1):

You should run the neo4j server on the machine that has the DB folder stored locally (i.e., the one that currently has the IP address 192.168.1.11). See the [installation instructions](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/).

After that, there are multiple ways to access the DB through the neo4j server. See the [Developer Manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/).